# Angular and TweenLite

Tags: angular, gsap

I have the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    list = [1, 2, 3];    

    onAdd() {
        this.list.push(1);
    } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</li>
<ul>
<button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
```

I want to apply a TweenLite animation to the elements addition. For example, a new element adds with animation `{left: '-100px'}`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need tweenlite, use a css class with the animation you want and add the class to the generated item you can use timeout to make sure it works without a glitch.